# contact info list not returning "error" even though it is returning the info

Tags: javascript

i am doing a codecademy.com javascript course and i am having an issue with my contact info completing. it is returning, but i am getting an error informing me that it is not returning for steve. I have been racking my brain on this one so much i can't see straight..

The link is as follows
http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-3bmfN/0/7

```
var friends = new Object();
friends.bill = new Object();
friends.steve = new Object();

friends.steve.firstName = "steve";
friends.steve.lastName = "jobs";
friends.steve.number = "317-222-3344";
friends.steve.address = ["one apple way","california","us"];

friends.bill.firstName = "bill";
friends.bill.lastName = "gates";
friends.bill.number = "327-332-3322";
friends.bill.address = ["one microsoft way","washington","us"];

var list = function (name){
    for(var key in name){
    console.log(friends[key]);
   }
};

var search = function(name){
    for(var key in friends){
    if(friends[key].firstName === name){
        console.log(key);
        return search;
     }
   }
};

search("bill");
search("steve");
list(friends);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test is looking for case sensitive names, and it looks for "Steve" first. Change each first name to title case and you will pass.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning search which is your function.
Just change it to what you want.

```
return friends[key];

var friends = new Object();
friends.bill = new Object();
friends.steve = new Object();

friends.steve.firstName = "Steve";
friends.steve.lastName = "jobs";
friends.steve.number = "317-222-3344";
friends.steve.address = ["one apple way","california","us"];

friends.bill.firstName = "Bill";
friends.bill.lastName = "gates";
friends.bill.number = "327-332-3322";
friends.bill.address = ["one microsoft way","washington","us"];

var list = function (name){
    for(var key in name){
    console.log(friends[key]);
   }
};

var search = function(name){
    for(var key in friends){
    if(friends[key].firstName === name){
        var f = friends[key];
        console.log(f.firstName,f.lastName,f.number,f.address);
        return f;
     }
   }
};

search("bill");
search("Steve");
```

Comment: Please always check the question exactly.
you wrote steve and bill. But the question mentioned "Bill" and "Steve".

Comment: so bill should come before steve for the info ?

Comment: No the important part is the first letter which should be capital